# Java нарезание строки по пробелам

Tags: java, строки

Производится чтение строки с набором данных

```
String GPS = TEXT.getText();
```

после чего нужно разобрать строку в 6 переменных (одна строка и 5 `double` разделение идет пробелами, а числа могут быть с разным числом цифр)
Например

```
String GPS="0013A2EDC121FEA1 32.679823 62.624853 23.1 10.65 0.65"
```

Нужно разобрать на

```
String ID="0013A2EDC121FEA1";
Double lat=32.679823;
Double lon=62.624853;
Double altitude= 23.1;
Double course = 10.65;
Double speed= 0.65;
```

Comment: Что не получается? Поидее `split` и обработка элементов массива. Всё

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String gps = "0013A2EDC121FEA1 32.679823 62.624853 23.1 10.65 0.65";
String[] strings = gps.split("\\s+");
String ID = strings[0];
Double lat = Double.parseDouble(strings[1]);
Double lon = Double.parseDouble(strings[2]);
Double altitude = Double.parseDouble(strings[3]);
Double course = Double.parseDouble(strings[4]);
Double speed = Double.parseDouble(strings[5]);
```